# How to find sum of power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}$ by differentiation and integration?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $$ S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n+2)} $$

Integrate the Taylor Series of $xe^x$ to show that S = 1 
Also, Differentiate the Taylor series of $\frac{e^x - 1}{x}$ to show that S = 1

For the integration one, I got $\int xe^x dx$ = $x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n+2)} x^n$ and pretty much stuck. I can see the S term but i have no idea how to move on from there

Comment: Show what you have tried, this isn't a homework site.

Comment: I have edited. Sorry about that. First time posting here

Comment: Hmm, if you plug in $x=1$ into the Taylor series of $\int{xe^x\text{ d}x}$, what do you get? Now, can you find out what $\int{xe^x\text{ d}x}$ is and just plug in $x=1$ for that? (Be careful that in integrating, you need to choose a constant of integration--what constant should you choose?)

Comment: @Joey Yeah, I'll get $\int xe^x dx$ = S, but when I integrate $\int xe^x dx$ i get $e^x(x-1) + C$ at x=1 i get -1 + C. Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: Well, plugging $x=1$ into $e^x(x-1)$ shouldn't yield $-1$, it should yield $0$. But that's not the issue: the indefinite integral should be $e^x(x-1)+C$ for some constant $C$. What constant should you pick? Well, what should the value at $x=0$ be?

Comment: Oh yes its 0 my bad. For the constant C, I know i should use it where $f(0)$, but I'm unsure which $f(x)$ I am referring to now.

Comment: What should your Taylor series equal at $x=0$? Whatever that's equal to, set it equal to $e^0(0-1)+C$ and you have your $C$.

Comment: Ok i got it now. The series is 0 at x=0, so my c should be 1. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) By integration. Let
$$F(t):=\int_0^t xe^x dx=[e^x(x-1)]_0^t=e^t(t-1)+1.$$
On the other hand
$$F(t)=\int_0^t xe^x dx=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \int_0^t\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}dx=
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{t^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)}.$$
Hence $S=F(1)=1$.

2) By differentiation. Let
$$f(x):=\frac{e^x - 1}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$
then
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^x}{x}-\frac{e^x - 1}{x^2}.$$
On the other hand
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(x^{n-1})'}{n!}=
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(n-1)x^{n-2}}{n!}=
\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!n}
=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!(n+2)}.$$
Hence $S=f'(1)=e-(e-1)=1$.

3) A telescoping approach. Note that
$$\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}=\frac{(n+1)}{(n+2)!}=\frac{(n+2)-1}{(n+2)!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{1}{n!(n+2)}=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}\right)=1-\frac{1}{(N+2)!}\to 1$$
as $N\to +\infty$, and we conclude that $S=1$.

Comment: The OP asked to use "differentiation and integration"

Comment: @Eugen Covaci You are right! I completed my answer with the requested approaches.

Comment: Thanks robert! Understood the part for differentiation now